# Virtual Machine Encoding

Tags: assembly, encoding, character-encoding, virtual-machine

When creating a Virtual Machine do you have to encode the instructions into 1's and 0's or is there anything wrong with interpreting the instruction directly using some form of custom assembly code? Like this:

```
load r1 #100
load r2 #110
add r3 r1 r2
```

Comment: it is all up to you.  The spim simulator takes ascii programs as an input. I dont off hand know if it assembles to binary then executes or executes based on interpretation.  It is likely much easier to assemble to binary then simulate, at the end of the day that is what you are going to do as you will need to have some numerical representation of the individual components, mnemonic, registers, immediates, to switch between execution paths.